# Laravel redirect on user registration

Tags: laravel, redirect

When a user has registered his/her new account, redirect to the profile page.
I know that to redirect a user to his/her account I would do:

> `<a href=**"account/Auth::user->username**>{{Auth::user->username}}</a>`

And i figured that within Laravel's RegisterController I could do the same with its `$redirectTo` property, like so:

> `protected $redirectTo = Auth::user()->username;`

But it does not seem to work, is there a way I could use the User model directly or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel auth system also covers that by providing a `redirectTo()` method that you can use instead of a `$redirectTo` variable.

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        
        return 'account/'.auth()->user()->username;
    }
}
```